# Why is $L'=\{u\#v^R ~|~ u,v \in L\}$ and $L\in RL$ a regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, context-free, regular-expressions

Define $L'=\{u\#v^R ~|~ u,v \in L\}$ and $L\in RL$ while $\#\notin \Sigma$

Why is $L'$ a regular language?

I have tried to construct the DFA of L, then with a # move to a copy of this DFA with flipped edges. I think this is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? One thing in mind homework questions are strictly prohibited here.

Comment: Also, what is $RL$?  Please define all non-standard notation that you use.  What's the context where you encountered this question?  Can you credit the original source?  Why do you believe it is regular?  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: This is not a homework question, just something I thought of while preparing for the exam. RL == Regular Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular languages are closed under reversal, therefore $L^R = \{v^R \mid v \in L\}$ is regular. Moreover, regular languages are closed under concatenation, therefore $L' = L \circ \{\#\} \circ L^R$ is regular.

Comment: Simple as that, thank you so much! :)